# How to insert a structure within a structure

Tags: matlab, insert, structure

I have a 1x1 structure called imu_data.txyzrxyz1.  It has one field called txyzrxyz1 and the value is 4877x7 double.  I just want to "copy and paste" row 62 into row 63 (double up that row) so that the structure now becomes a 4878x7 structure.  I've tried the following, with other versions without success:

```
    extra_63 = imu_data.txyzrxyz1(63,:);
    imu_data2.txyzrxyz1 = [{imu_data.txyzrxyz1(1:62,:) extra_63 imu_data.txyzrxyz1(63:end,:)}]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can index the row to duplicate twice while matrix indexing:

```
row_to_duplicate = 63;

yourdata = rand(100,10);
yourstruct.data = yourdata;
yourstruct.data = yourstruct.data([1:row_to_duplicate, row_to_duplicate:end],:)
```

So in case of 63, `1:row_to_duplicate` will create a column vector from `1:63`, and `row_to_duplicate:end` will create a column vector from `63:100` in this example. When combining these, 63 will occur twice, hence that row is duplicated.

You were almost there, you only had to get rid of the `{}`'s and put the data in the right orientation by using `;` instead of a space between matrix entries to vertically concatenate instead of horizontally:

```
extra_63 = imu_data.txyzrxyz1(63,:);
imu_data2.txyzrxyz1 = [imu_data.txyzrxyz1(1:62,:); extra_63; imu_data.txyzrxyz1(63:end,:)]
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Yes I wanted to do it at the indexing.